# How to round currency in gridview to significant figures?

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, gridview, currency

I have a gridview pulling from a SQL table and it contains varying dollar figures.  They're in thousands, millions or billions.  I'm currently using {0:c0} but I'm interested in slimming this down so that I will show only three significant figures.

For instance, I'd like $3,411,216,512.07 to display as $3.41B; while $1,066,555.54 would be displayed as $1.07M.

Is there a simple way to do this in ASP.NET or do I need to break out the jQuery?  Or alternatively, should I do it in C# OnRowDataBound?

Comment: Can you modify the data in the datasource before binding it to the gridview?

Comment: I can.  The question then becomes, is it better to do this in SQL using Surreal Dreams' approach and adding another column for each value or is it better to do it in C# using the other two answers?

Ultimately we're only talking a couple hundred rows (most are hidden to the user until asked for), so I doubt I'd see a performance issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could convert the number to a string, grab the first four characters - assuming a pure number with no units, commas, etc - convert it back to a number, round it off, and then count the length of the original string to decide where to put the decimal point and what to label it with, be it B, M, K, etc.  I'd suggest doing it server-side, I don't see a point in doing it in the browser unless you want to make it interactive somehow.

Answer (score 0):

I'd do it in OnRowDataBound. Check to see if your number is bigger than a billion, divide it by a billion, string.format a "B" on the end of it and the currency symbol on the front then return.
Check to see if the number is greater than a million... etc

You could probably write an algorithm to dynamically handle it, but as this is money and it's probably limited to trillions doing it manually should be much faster.

Answer (score 0):

```
    if(n>999999)
    {
    string number = Convert.ToString(n.slice[0,3]) + "M";
    ... 
//> (apply it to your datatable and then show it (in datagridview if that's
//> what you're using)
    }
   else if (n>...)
```

Repeat that for cases where it's over a Bilion,etc but there is still the need to check where the comma is going to be. I'm not sure how to do it. That's just how you can get the first 3 numbers as you wanted and applying "B" or "M".